# Can pressure in bars be equated to flow in litres per second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I have a 160 mm water pipe at 5 bar pressure.What is the flow in litres per sec? I want to fit a hydro turbine to the outlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculation of Pressure from flow rate of water](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127760/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pressure difference and flow rates are related. You can see this analogous to voltage and current in electrical systems. They are related via [hydraulic conductance or resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_conductivity) or via [friction factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae).